# Neo4j 4 and .NET Core Identity Framework

Tags: asp.net-core, neo4j, cypher, asp.net-identity

I want to use .NET Core Identity Framework with the new Neo4j version 4 in ASP.net Core but any implementation I looked for, does not support the new Neo4j.
Like:

[Neo4j.AspNet.Identity.Core](https://github.com/cskardon/Neo4j.AspNet.Identity.Core#neo4jaspnetidentitycore)

[Neo4j.AspNetCore.Identity](https://github.com/francnuec/Neo4j.AspNetCore.Identity)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use .NET Core Identity Framework with the new Neo4j version 4 in ASP.net Core but any implementation I looked for, does not support the new Neo4j.

As you mentioned, most of existing example and github demo are built on older version .NET Core and Neo4j, which might not work well with the application built on the latest SDK.

If you do want to implement ASP.NET Core Identity with the new Neo4j, you can refer to the following doc to create a customized storage provider for ASP.NET Core Identity.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1